# ms access sql - if y = a, update field to x , elseif elseif

Tags: sql, if-statement, ms-access-2010

I am trying to populate a field in MS Access. The string I'd like to populate the field with depends on the string in another column. Is there a way to update the same field with different values depending on the value of another field?

I tried selecting the field to be populated multiple times in Query Designer, but it returns a message saying the output field was duplicated.

i.e.

```
Col1 Populated
x       1
x       1
y       2
j       10
y       2
j       10
x       1
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You may need to nest you IF statements, not write a seperate if statement in multiple fields (which are the same field duplicates). Can you share your logic. We can probably write up an UPDATE query that you can copy/paste in and switch back over to designer to see.

Answer (score 0):

This may help as a start:

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE (
Col1 NVARCHAR(1)
,Populated  INT 
)

INSERT INTO @Temp
VALUES 
 ('x',1)
,('x',1)
,('y',2)
,('j',10)
,('y',2)
,('j',10)
,('x',1)

DECLARE @InputA INT
SET @InputA =  2

DECLARE @Y INT 
SELECT @Y = (SELECT Top 1 Populated FROM @Temp WHERE Col1 = 'Y')

DECLARE @x INT 
SELECT @x = (SELECT Top 1 Populated FROM @Temp WHERE Col1 = 'x')


SELECT 
    Col1 
    ,Populated 
    ,CASE WHEN Populated = @InputA THEN @X 
          ELSE Populated
          END 
FROM @Temp
```